# Java selector.select() blocking thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio

I'm trying to run a NIO Server in it's own Thread.

In my run function I defined:

```
while(running)
{
   System.out.println("Server running!");
   try
   {
      this.selector.select();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

The run loops only runs one time and then it's stuck.
Without the whole try block it works.

It the selector.select() blocking somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says,

> This method performs a blocking selection operation. It returns only after at least one channel is selected, this selector's wakeup method is invoked, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever comes first.

So it should block until a channel is selected.

For non-blocking select/busy loop, try *selectNow* method.

Comment: Meaning, that it blocks as long as I connect a client to it?

Comment: It _should_ block until either a channel is selected, you interrupt the thread, or you wake the thread.  The documentation is pretty clear about this.

Comment: You are right, I should have seen that. I was just convinced that putting the server in non-blocking mode would have the server loop run all the time.

Comment: @JamieFlowers The I/O is non-blocking. select() is a blocking operation.